# Excel 2010 on importing Access datasource: Can I just dump the data into the worksheet without maintaining a connection to the Access table?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-access, import

I am able to successfully import an Access .accdb table into my Excel 2010 worksheet.  However, it still seems to maintain a connection to the data.  This is an inconvenience for me because I have to manually disconnect it in the event that I need to use a third party program to export data into the Access database again.  Otherwise, it throws an exception saying that the Access database is in use by another application.

Is there a way to just to a one-time dump into the worksheet where no connections are maintained at all so my workflow is as smooth as it can be?

Comment: [these](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/exchange-copy-import-export-data-between-excel-and-access-HA010096300.aspx) instructions are for 2007, but can't you just copy/paste? You could also just open the db with excel and save-as xls to have a copy

Comment: I don't have Access on my work PC, so I have to import the table through Excel.  That link you showed seems to require Access except for the import through Excel which I've already been doing.  I am guessing the only way to do what I want is how I've already been doing it, which is to connect to Access then remove the connection manually.

Comment: Just open the DB with excel and use `save as` to save a copy with no links. Go to `data - connections - remove` to remove the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the data the usual way, but break the connection at `data - connections` select the connection and hit `remove`

Comment: Yep, this is pretty much the only option I came across.  Not a big deal, but I was hoping for one less step in the process of automating this manual task.  Thank.